# use string variables in pattern for regex

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to extract some urls from the richtextbox1 to the listbox1.

Urls are like this: http://something.com/fixed_value/somethingelse/

I don't know how to make the right regex pattern with the changing string variables(string something, somethingelse).

Please help me.

Thank you.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = theusercp

dim baseurl as string = "http://something.com/"
dim soelse as string = "somethingelse"

 Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(baseurl+"fixed_value/"+somethingelse)
'I have no idea what I'm doing with regex pattern.
'I have to combine baseurl/fixed_value/somethingelse to get the right urls.
'I hope to get the list of http://something.com/fixed_value/somethingelse/

 Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(theusercp)
 For Each itemcode As Match In matches
            ListBox1.Items.Add(itemcode.Value)
        Next
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Regular expressions have various characters that can be used in special ways. A good cheat sheet can be found [here](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

To answer your question, try this:

```
Dim exp = (baseurl + "fixed_value/" + somethingelse).Replace("/", "\/")

Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(exp)
```

Comment: Also `^http:\/\/something.com\/fixed_value\/somethingelse`. Basically you need to escape your forward slashes.

Comment: The baseurl value and somethingelse changes all the time. These are random values I just simply put something.com and somethingelse in above example to simplify the question. I want to know how to use multiple strings in the pattern.

Comment: I've edited my post to something a little more useful. You can also try the [Regex Fiddle](http://refiddle.com/) website if you want to test different expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Set your regex expression to below and see if it helps..

```
  http://([A-Za-z0-9\-.]+)\/fixed_value/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\/$
```